# (Class Booking Function) Prompt a user that they have selected a Weekend Date before they click Submit on HTML Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

### Intro to the Problem

I am currently developing a Booking Function, Members are able to purchase class packages of two different types, the first being a "Weekday Only" package whilst the other package allows for "All-Days".

I do not want to disable the selection of Weekends and Public Holidays for "Weekday Only" Package holders as they would still need to be able to book these dates albeit with additional costs.

Was wondering if there is any way to inform a "Weekday Only" Package holder that they have selected a Weekend/Public Holiday before they click submit on the HTML form.

### The current method

On the Member's Home page they would be able to click the "Book a Class" button as long as their current account has an active package, Saving package information in the mysql as states of '0 = No Package' , '1 = Weekday Only Package' and '2 = Any-Day Package'.

Upon clicking the "Book a Class" button they are redirected to a form that allows the user to select a Date and a Class Slot. Upon submitting the form the day is checked based on the submitted date, If the Member package is state = '1' and the date selected falls on Saturday/Sunday it would prompt the member about the additional costs, before allowing the member to confirm the booking.

The current method is only able to check the date after the submit button has been hit, and the form submitted,

Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: You could use ajax to check this before submitting the form. Or, if you have the information on the user, you could add it to a hidden field and use javascript to validate.

Comment: Looking at this from a UX standpoint, I would suggest disabling the weekend dates and put a link on the page saying "Or choose a period that includes weekends" which leads to a new page.

Comment: @MrLister so it checks if you have a Weekday package - if true, then bring you to a booking form with already disabled weekend dates (and Public Holidays).
The user would have to actively want to select a Weekend/PH date. Instead of being prompted that they selected one.

Definitely does sound better for the UX. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, you can add an event listener that will fire a handler function that validates the date to determine if it's on a weekend or not every time the input changes.

In the aforementioned function, you can check if it's the weekend using the **[getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)** method to validate, something like the code/pseudocode below could be a good start:

```
let yourDateField = document.getElementByID("you-date-field");

yourDateField.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {

    let selectedDate = new Date(yourDateField.value);

    let day = selectedDate.getDay();

    if(day === 6){

      alert("The date you chose is on a Saturday");

    }
    else if(day === 0){

      alert("The date you chose is on a Sunday");

    }else{

      //Proceed with class signup.

    }

});
```

The answer assumes that you don't need to check the database before making the validation.

Comment: Thank you, Will accept it as an answer for this question. Though will also be looking into what CUGreen commented about using ajax.